# Replacing spaces in a string with a word in a random fashion c#

Tags: c#, string, random

I am trying  to figure out how to replace a space found in a string with the word "car", but I want it to replace it in a random order, like only some of the spaces would be replaces with "car" for example:

Input: "Hi welcome to the autobody shop how can I help you today?"
Output: "Hi car welcome to car autobody shop how car I help car you today?"

As you see, only some spaces have been replaced with the word "car". I hope someone could help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
static Random random = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "Hi welcome to the autobody shop how can I help you today?";
    string output = input;

    for (int i = output.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (output[i] == ' ' && random.Next(2) == 1)
            output = output.Insert(i, " car");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

You can decrease the probability by increasing the `x` value in `random.Next(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this. For instance, you could replace some percentage of words with "car", or for each individual word you could have a chance that it'll be replaced. I'm going to assume you want to go for the latter.

What you'd want to do is **loop through each word in the sentence, and with some chance, replace that word with a different one**.

A method would look something like this:

```
private string ReplaceRandomWords(string original, string replacement, int replacementChance) 
    {
        // Split into words
        string[] words = original.Split(' ');

        Random random = new Random();

        // Loop through each word
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {

            // Roll a random number between one and 100
            int roll = random.Next(1, 100); 

            // If we rolled lower than our chance, replace that word
            if (roll <= replacementChance) {
                words[i] = replacement;
            }
        }

        // Put the words back into a sentence
        return string.Join(" ", words);
    }
```

Using the above with the following code will produce the desired results

```
    string sentence = "Hi welcome to the autobody shop how can I help you today?";
    string replacement = "car";
    int chanceToReplace = 25;

    string newSentence = ReplaceRandomWords(sentence, replacement, chanceToReplace);
```

Some output examples:

```
Hi welcome to car autobody shop how car car help you today?
car welcome to the autobody shop how car car help you car
Hi welcome car the autobody car how can car help you car
```

Be aware that this example may not be properly random.